# Custom Code in Reporting Services 2008 makes cell show #Error

Tags: .net, vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have the following code in "Custom Code" in SSRS 2008. It works fine in VS2008 but it won't run on the server:

```
Public Shared Function Ns(ByVal num as Object, ByVal def as Object) as Object
  if IsNothing(num) OrElse Not IsNumeric(num) OrElse System.Double.IsNaN(num) then 
      return def
  else  
      return num
  end if
End Function
```

I am referencing it as "Code.Ns(..., ...)" in my fields in SSRS 2008. In VS2008's renderer it seems like it is executing just fine. When I try to render it programatically using a custom .NET application the report renders with all the fields except for the custom code parts which look like: #Error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reporting Services 2008 (NOT R2) returns different types depending on what it read from the database. (see [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_pfe_blog/archive/2009/07/10/sum-of-a-sql-analysis-services-calculated-measure-within-a-reporting-services-report-gives-error.aspx) for a good explanation). If you return an Object from a sub as I was doing above then the SUM() function in SSRS 2008 gets messed up because you might be summing different types. This is what I was doing in one of my cells in SSRS:

```
Sum(Ns(<some database field>, 0)
```

Although this DOES work on SSRS 2008 R2 (on my test machine), it DOESN'T WORK ON SSRS 2008 without R2 (my production machine).